# vis.js Get Y value in a 2dgraph

Tags: javascript, cursor, axis, vis.js

I'm using vis.js to diplay some dataset like on a 2dgraph :

```
var data_lat=[
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:49.257',y:48.66081132,group:0},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:51.257',y:48.66081132,group:0},
...
```

I have put a draggable cursor on that graph with

```
graph_lat.addCustomTime(time[0].t, '1');
```

and I would ike to display the curent value of y depending of the position of my cursor.

I've looked though vis.js doc but I didn't find anything

---

/**/EDIT TO ANSWER/**/

This is the function i created to get the y value BUT : only for array with only one group in it

```
function closest (time, arr) {
var mid, time_mid;
var lo = 0;
var hi = arr.length - 1;
var time_number=moment(time).format('x');
//console.log(time_number);
while (hi - lo > 1) {
    mid = Math.floor ((lo + hi) / 2);
    time_mid=moment(arr[mid].x).format('x');
    if (time_mid < time_number) {
        lo = mid;
    } else {
        hi = mid;
    }
}
if (time_number - moment(arr[lo].x).format('x') <= moment(arr[hi].x).format('x') - time_number) {
    return arr[lo].y;
}
return arr[hi].y;
```

}

and here the one for array with many group (like many `y` for one `x` value) like this array :

```
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:49.257',y:0,group:8},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:49.257',y:0,group:9},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:49.257',y:0,group:10},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:49.257',y:0,group:11},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:51.257',y:9,group:8},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:51.257',y:6,group:9},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:51.257',y:0,group:10},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:51.257',y:15,group:11},
{x:'2016-02-05T07:58:53.257',y:9,group:8}

function closest_multi_group (time, arr, groupID) {
var mid, time_mid;
var lo = 0;
var hi = arr.length - 1;
var time_number=moment(time).format('x');
//console.log(time_number);
while (hi - lo > 1) {
    mid = Math.floor ((lo + hi) / 2);
    time_mid=moment(arr[mid].x).format('x');
    if (time_mid < time_number) {
        lo = mid;
    } else {
        hi = mid;
    }
}
console.log((time_number - moment(arr[lo].x).format('x'))+'<='+(moment(arr[hi].x).format('x') - time_number));
if (time_number - moment(arr[lo].x).format('x') <= moment(arr[hi].x).format('x') - time_number) {
    console.log(arr[lo]);

    if(arr[lo+1].group < arr[lo].group){
        while(arr[lo].group!=groupID){

            lo--;
            console.log('lo-- '+lo);
        }
    }
    else{
        while(arr[lo].group!=groupID){

            lo++;
            console.log('lo++ '+lo);
        }
    }
    return arr[lo].y;
}

if(arr[hi-1].group > arr[hi].group){
    console.log(arr[hi]);
    while(arr[hi].group!=groupID){

        hi++;
        console.log('hi++ '+hi);
    }
}
else{
    console.log(arr[hi]);
    while(arr[hi].group!=groupID){

        hi--;
        console.log('hi-- '+hi);
    }
}
return arr[hi].y;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event `timechange` gives you the current time of the custom time bar when being dragged. That is your `x`. With this time, you can loop over your `data_lat` to find the data point closest to `x` and display the corresponding `y` value somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but look at my data : it's to precise, when i'm trying to get my `y` value by `x` time like `2016-02-05T07:58:49.257` there is no chance that when moving the cursor i will get back that exact value. And i can not be less precise on my time data.

Comment: If there are 10 data points rendered within the same pixel on screen, there is no way you can detect which one is closest. In that case you'll have to zoom in or something like that.